# How to sync object between two s3 buckets when the only difference is a tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, tags, synchronization

There are two buckets within single account. Both buckets are huge (few TB). Buckets were synced few days ago but lately some of the files in the source bucket were given a tag (two tags to be precise). Does anyone know of a way to re-sync buckets so that objects in destination bucket are identical including tags? `aws s3 sync` does not handle that.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to **write your own code** to identify such objects and re-copy them.

To make this easier, you could activate [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which can provide a daily file listing all objects in a bucket, <strike>including tags</strike>.

Your program could read this file for both buckets, do comparisons, then copy the objects that have different tags.

Comment: That's what I thought as I haven't found anything in the web. Thank you for the tip on Inventory.

Comment: @JohnR I don't think Amazon S3 Inventory supports user tags.  If it does that would a life saver for me.  Could you confirm that tags are supported and, if so, send documentation on how to configure the report to include them?

Comment: @MrSuaveh You're right -- S3 inventory doesn't seem to include object-level tags.